# How to implement a multi column combo box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox

I want to implement a multi column combo box using C#. A sample screen shot of what I'm looking for can be found in [THIS LINK](https://amoghnatu.net/2013/05/14/how-to-implement-a-multi-column-dropdown-list-see-attached-image-for-more-clarity/).

I have done some search and [found a link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/08/04/how-to-create-a-multi-column-auto-complete-drop-down-box-in-lightswitch.aspx) where he is pretty much doing the same but the author used LightSwitch. I'm not really much aware of LightSwitch. Is there any way to do it simply using C#, ASP.NET?

Can someone suggest a way to implement it?

Comment: have you seen anything like this anywhere before.. I am struggling to imagine what you are talking about (if not either a multi-select list box or series of chained drop downs)

Comment: Can you please check this: http://wp.me/p2AZUy-6k